# Ruby match against class vars inside objects within array

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, matching

I am by no means an expert, and I've run into a little snag when handling objects via a Readline input.

I have a Player class, an Inventory class, and an Item class, and I want the player to be able to type "wear brick" and have it match an Item.name within the array Inventory.contents and add that item to Player.worn. Here's what I have:

```
class Player
  def wear(item)
    @worn << item
  end
end

class Inventory
  attr_accessor :contents
  def initialize
    @contents = []
    @stick = Item.new('a brown stick', 'long and pointy')
    @brick = Item.new('a red brick', 'rough and heavy')
    @contents << @stick
    @contents << @brick
  end
  def list_contents
    @contents.each {|item| puts item.name }
    nil
  end
end

class Item
  attr_accessor :name, :desc
  def initialize(name, desc)
    @name = name
    @desc = desc
  end
end

player = Player.new
inv = Inventory.new
```

I have a Readline prompt to accept the first token of an input string as a command, here 'wear' as a case, but I'm having a hard time grasping how to match the subsequent string within a object inside an array of objects with one word.

inv.contents.inspect:

```
[#<Item:0x007fcf61935bb0 @name="a brown stick", @desc="long and pointy">, #<Item:0x007fcf61935b38 @name="a red brick", @desc="rough and heavy">]
```

How could I have "wear brick" search through the Array inv.contents to match @name="a red brick" and select that item to input into Player.wear?

---

@c650 : thank you. that looks to have solved it!

New Class:

```
class Player
  def initialize
    @inventory = Inventory.new
    @worn = []
    @input = "brick"
  end
  def wear(keyword)
    @inventory.contents.map{|x| @worn << x and @inventory.contents.delete(x) if x.name.include?(keyword) }
  end
end
```

Comment: You could try `inv.contents.map{|x| <do something >if x.name == input.split(' ').first }`. Does this help at all?

Comment: What about [regexp matching](http://codepad.org/WY9jaoX9)?

Comment: Thanks c650. Since I'm aiming at just using one word to do the match and I already have a case grabbing the command 'wear' out of the input, using .include?(keyword) does the trick. If you'd like to throw that into an answer I'll gladly accept it.